# OCR-Software sought

Tags: python, python3, ocr

What is recommended commercially free usable OCR-Software? It should be accessible via Python or a Python library. And it should run under Linux.

The one I came across myself is tesseract. Are there others?

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OCR

Answer (score 1):

I have used **pytesser**, it worked alright.

https://code.google.com/p/pytesser/